# GatsbyJS blog not compiling anymore after "npm update"?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, gatsby

If it's a Gatsby, webpack or npm issue i don't understand yet.

I did these commands in terminal and they seem to have started the issue, trying to fix a material-ui "Popper" module that had a "could not find module" error.

```
npm install react-popper@next --save    
npm install avj    
npm install --save-dev webpack    
npm install & npm update
```

Terminal:

> error There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby
>   may not be installed. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"?
>
> [image]
>     Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/removeAndDo'

package.json

```
{
  "name": "auto-club-reviews",
  "description": "Auto Club Reviews Blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Sofianu Alin",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "gatsby": "^1.9.277",
    "gatsby-link": "^1.6.46",
    "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^1.3.25",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.0.31",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^1.0.18",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^2.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-next": "^1.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^1.6.48",
    "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^1.7.19",
    "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^1.5.37",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^1.5.67",
    "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^1.4.20",
    "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^1.4.12",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^1.3.54",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^1.5.39",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^1.7.44",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^1.6.27",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-hover": "^1.3.2",
    "react-popper": "^1.0.2",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "^1.14.2",
    "webpack": "^4.16.5",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog#readme",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "n/a",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gatsby develop",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern public .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "format": "prettier --trailing-comma es5 --no-semi --single-quote --write 'src/**/*.js' 'src/**/*.md'",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
    "fix-semi": "eslint --quiet --ignore-pattern node_modules --ignore-pattern public --parser babel-eslint --no-eslintrc --rule '{\"semi\": [2, \"never\"], \"no-extra-semi\": [2]}' --fix gatsby-node.js"
  }
}
```

Also tried to:

delete node_modules then npm install;

uninstall "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0" and install webpack-commander;

uninstall extract-text-webpack-plugin that seemed to be complained about in terminal;

Any ideas comrades?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you been experimenting with Gatsby v2? Your `package.json` shows React v16, which is a `peerDependency` of Gatsby v2, but not of Gatsby v1. In Gatsby v1 (which is what you have in `package.json`) you should not install React directly, it's installed as a dependency of Gatsby.

Webpack is also (both v1 and v2) a dependency of Gatsby. I don't think you should have it in `package.json` as a top level dependency.

I would recommend starting with a clean Gatsby starter, then copying your `gatsby-node.js`, `gatsby-config.js`, components, content, etc, into that project. Leave the `package.json` file. Then run `npm install --save` for every package that you explicitly `import` or `require`. Hopefully that gets you back to a working site.

Sidenote, personally, I would also recommend `yarn` over `npm`.

Comment: Thank you! i'm pretty sure this would have worked if wasn't so lazy to install 91 modules like this:) or maybe there is a smart way to do it. A friend recommended replacing package.json AND package.lock.json with some previous versions of them, delete node_modules and run npm install, wich it did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> Gatsby clean-cache

Then delete node modules

and then

> yarn start/npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).